# transpose csv in .C

Tags: c, csv, transpose

I have created a program that calculates interest and payment in `.c`. As part of the program I have to print to a `.csv`, however, it needs to be formatted into rows instead of columns. Is there a way to transpose the csv at the end of the program?

All other info I found was in python or C++.

Comment: Excel can help you.

Comment: I know that excel can help me, however as part of my code I am required to print horizontally anyway within the program

Comment: I am still not really sure what you want. Having columns of records instead of rows of records is a bit strange. Your response to P__J__'s good solution example is strange too: _do you have a matrix to transpose or not_????

Comment: well no i just have the csv file in excel, which was made from a range of calcuations earlier on in the program.

the data is 7x360 cells

Comment: and I have to transpose it because that's what my professor wants

Answer (score 0):

File has to be opened for writing before function call

```
void transposeandprint(FILE *f, double *array, size_t r, size_t c)
{
    for(size_t col = 0; col < c; col++)
    {
        for(size_t row = 0; row < r; row++)
        {
            fprintf(f, "%f%s", array[row * c + col], row == r  - 1 ? "\n" : ",");
        }
    }
}

double data[3][5] = 
{
    {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0},
    {1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1},
    {1.2, 2.2, 3.2, 4.2, 5.2},
};

int main()
{
    transposeandprint(stdout, data, 3, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've got a vague idea of what you are doing in your code, however, I am confused what the double data section is doing and do I have to input that matrix myself?

Comment: To be honest I do not understand your question.